# Is there a backup of kforge.ros.org anywhere?

Tags: ros, kforge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I occasionally find myself wanting to resurrect an old package that was hosted on kforge, and have been having to rely on forking some random person's fork (if I'm lucky). Did somebody manage to grab a backup before it was taken down?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119086/is-there-a-backup-of-kforge.ros.org-anywhere?/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2014-01-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-17**:
Is there a specific package you're looking for?

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-01-18**:
At the moment, arm_navigation_experimental, but there have been a few others in the past that I don't remember.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-29**:
Is the project megatree now hosted somewhere else? Wiki also says it's still at kforge....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The arm_navigation and arm_navigation_experimental stacks are available on Willow Garage's github:

- https://github.com/willowgarage/arm_navigation
- https://github.com/willowgarage/arm_navigation_experimental

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-29**:
Is the project megatree now hosted somewhere else? Wiki also says it's still at kforge....

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-06-14**:
I'm looking for the source code for `turtlebot_node` which belongs to `turtlebot package`. is ther any backup for that? the kforge is down.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-06-15**:
turtlebot_node appears to be obsolete, and the turltebot package has moved to github: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot . If you really need the turtlebot node, it's still present in the git history for that repository.